# How can I use interpolation to specify element directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a view in angular.js where I add a dynamic set of templates, each wrapped up in a directive. The directive names correspond to some string property from a set of objects. I need a way add the directives without knowing in advance which ones will be needed.

This project uses Angular 1.5 with webpack.

Here's a boiled down version of the code:

set of objects:

```
$scope.items = [
    { name: "a", id: 1 },
    { name: "b", id: 2 }
]
```

directives:

```
angular.module('myAmazingModule')
    .directive('aDetails', () => ({
        scope: false,
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'myRavishingController',
        template: require("./a.html")
    }))
    .directive('bDetails',() => ({
        scope: false,
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'myRavishingController',
        template: require("./b.html")
    }));
```

view:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>
        <{{item.name}}-details/>
    </div>
</li>
```

so that eventually the rendered view will look like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>
        <a-details/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b-details/>
    </div>
</li>
```

How do I do this?

I do not mind other approaches, as long as I can inline the details templates, rather then separately fetching them over http.

Comment: I do this, kinda a 'proxy' directive. The logic is to use $compile in the `link` method. Don't forget to delete the newScope when you re-execute $compile. I'll search in my code later to give you a correct implementation.

Comment: And use $templateCache to cache your directives into your app, there won't be any http call. Good package is https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache if you use gulp

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-include`:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div ng-controller="myRavishingController"
        ng-include="'./'+item.name+'.html'">
   </div>
</li>
```

---

> I want to inline it to avoid the http call.

Avoid http calls by loading templates directly into the template cache with one of two ways:

- in a script tag,
- or by consuming the `$templateCache` service directly.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $templateCache Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)

Comment: Yes of course, but that fetches the template over http. I want to inline it to avoid the http call.

Comment: Avoid http calls by loading templates directly into the template cache. See update to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any html with directives like this:

```
const el = $compile(myHtmlWithDirectives)($scope);
$element.append(el);
```

But usually this is not the best way, I will just give a bit more detailed answer with use of `ng-include` (which actully calls `$compile` for you):

Add templates e.g. in module.run: [You can also add templates in html, but when they are required in multiple places, i prefer add them directly]

```
app.module('myModule').run($templateCache => {
  $templateCache.put('tplA', '<a-details></a-details>'); // or webpack require
  $templateCache.put('tplB', '<b-details></b-details>');
  $templateCache.put('anotherTemplate', '<input ng-model="item.x">');
})
```

Your model now is:

```
$scope.items = [
    { name: "a", template: 'tplA' },
    { name: "b", template: 'tplB' },
    { name: "c", template: 'anotherTemplate', x: 'editableField' }
]
```

And html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div ng-include="item.template">
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: -1 because ng-include isn't the right solution. A proxy directive has to be written with a correct $compile use. TemplateCache should never be called by the developper, it's a hack.

Comment: When you say that something is bad - go a bit deeper and explain why. Is it design anti-pattern? Does it work slow? It does not scale?

Comment: +1 for your answer. Using `$compile` has a lot of pitfalls for new AngularJS programmers. The `ng-include` directive avoids those pitfalls. The `ng-include` directive creates a scope for the template's watchers and destroys the scope properly when the template changes. The `ng-include` also has the proper hooks for animation.

Comment: You don't lower the answer quality because you suspect the programmer isn't enough good into a technology. The power of angularjs is the directive/component structuration. Using ng-include will work, but it will be a nightmare to maintain later. Inside the ng-included template, you use directly the parent $scope, you are not free to use the variables names you would like. This is just a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use **dynamic directives**, you can create a custom directive like I did in this plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/n9c0ws?p=preview

Here is the code of the desired directive:

```
app.directive('myProxy', function($compile) {
  return {
    template: '<div>Never Shown</div>',
    scope: {
      type: '=',
      arg1: '=',
      arg2: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
      var childScope = null;

      $scope.disable = () => {
        // remove the inside
        $scope.changeView('<div></div>');
      };

      $scope.changeView = function(html) {
        // if we already had instanciated a directive
        // then remove it, will trigger all $destroy of children
        // directives and remove
        // the $watch bindings
        if(childScope)
          childScope.$destroy();

        console.log(html);

        // create a new scope for the new directive
        childScope = $scope.$new();
        element.html(html);
        $compile(element.contents())(childScope);
      };

      $scope.disable();
    },
    // controller is called first
    controller: function($scope) {

      var refreshData = () => {
        this.arg1 = $scope.arg1;
        this.arg2 = $scope.arg2;
      };

      // if the target-directive type is changed, then we have to 
      // change the template
      $scope.$watch('type', function() {
        this.type = $scope.type;

        refreshData();

        var html = "<div " + this.type + " ";
        html += 'data-arg1="$ctrl.arg1" ';
        html += 'data-arg2="$ctrl.arg2"';
        html += "></div>";

        $scope.changeView(html);
      });

      // if one of the argument of the target-directive is changed, just change
      // the value of $ctrl.argX, they will be updated via $digest
      $scope.$watchGroup(['arg1', 'arg2'], function() {
        refreshData();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The general idea is:

- we want `data-type` to be able to specify the name of the directive to display
- the other declared arguments will be passed to the targeted directives.
- firstly in the link, we declare a function able to create a subdirective via $compile . 'link' is called after controller, so in controller you have to call it in an async way (in the $watch)
- secondly, in the controller:

  - if the `type` of the directive changes, we rewrite the html to invoke the target-directive
  - if the other arguments are updated, we just update $ctrl.argX and angularjs will trigger $watch in the children and update the views correctly.

This implementation is OK if your target directives all share the same arguments. I didn't go further.

If you want to make a more dynamic version of it, I think you could set `scope: true` and have to use the attrs to find the arguments to pass to the target-directive.

Plus, you should use templates like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache to transform your templates in code that you can concatenate into your javascript application. It will be way faster.